# Send application dll from one system to another without File.Copy()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment

How to send **application dll** from one system to another without **File.Copy()** in C#? May be by FileStream,  any Idea ?

I m using web Service

Web service Code

```
    public string fileUpdates(string filesPath)
    {                      
        //System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(filesPath);
        //string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(filesPath);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filesPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filesPath);
        string s=fi.Extension;
        byte[] byteArr = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(byteArr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
        string data=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArr);

        return data;
    }
```

on Client Side

```
                   fileDa = wcf3.fileUpdates(listItem);
                   byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileDa);
                   fileData = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

                    int Length = 256;
                    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
                    int bytesRead = fileData.Read(buffer, 0, Length);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = fileData.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                    }


                    //fileData.Close();
                    //writeStream.Close();
```

Comment: Why dont you want to use `File.Copy()`? And what about `Serialization` ?

Comment: files that i will send may be big enough that serialization will fail

Answer (score 2):

You could use network sockets - [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) in conjunction with a [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx). Or if you want to get a level higher up you could use the HTTP protocol which would probably be easier. So on the remote machine you could have a web server running an ASP.NET application that will receive the file and on the client side simply send the file using an HTTP request.

Comment: but can i send dll file with filestream ...?

Comment: No. A `FileStream` is just a pointer to the file itself. It can be used to read/write to the file but not send it anywhere.

Comment: I m already using fileStream to write file on other system what on that i m losing file Version and Product Version...

Comment: So you are writing the file to a network share? Could you show your code?

Comment: No i m not using Network share i m reading file through web Service and on other system i m getting it in bytes and saving on system.......

Comment: Alright, could you then show us how you are currently reading and saving the file?

Comment: @Rahul With this code you use the "transparent connection" that windows offer, the file system over tcp ip. If you won to do it direct you must change that way, and direct use, ether TcpListener/Client, or http, or ftp.

Comment: can you give me example how to send via HTTP Protocol as I am New on .Net

Answer (score 0):

To move files from one computer to the other you need to have setup a server, and a client.

The server can be a web server, or an ftp server.

And from the part of the client you use code to retrieve the file via http, or ftp.

One simple example: [Download files using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457856/download-files-using-asp-net)

I suggest http from the moment you say asp.net, and you probably have iss install and running, you only then need to place the file on the correct url.

Comment: but can i send dll file with filestream ...?

Comment: @user1653769 Darin all ready answer to that, actually what I have give you here is how to get the file, not how to send it. How ever is very close to that, if you have the server setup and run, the client can send it.